# How to get the total number of fields with a certain value on PHP-MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have 20 columns named as `qa1, qa2, qa3 up to qa20` which will hold the value of either **YES** or **NO**.
How would I get the number of columns that holds the value of **YES** and the number of columns that hold the value of **NO**.

Addition:
The table description is like this:

```
examid int,
firstname varchar(20),
middlename varchar(20),
lastname varchar(20),
q1 varchar(1),
q2 varchar(1), .... up to q20(1)
```

For ex. The test data would be

```
q1 = y
q2 = n
q3 = y
q4 = n
q5 = y
q6 = n
q7 = y
q8 = n
q9 = y
q10 = y
```

I would like to get:

answer for `y = 6`
answer for `n = 4`

---

I figured it out, using php and mysql I came to:

```
$yescounter = 0;
$nocounter = 0;
for($x1 = 1; $x1<= 20; $x1++){
$trial1 = mysql_query("SELECT qanswer$x1 FROM tb_erm_exam_results WHERE qanswer$x1='y'");
$t1 = mysql_num_rows($trial1);
if($t1 == 1) { $yescounter++; } else { $nocounter++; }
}
echo "YES is: ".$yescounter." while NO is:".$nocounter;
```

which just gives the same result but without complicated mysql queries.

Comment: As Barmar says, see normalization. A database table is not a spreadsheet.

Comment: Can you post sample input data and the expected result? The accepted answer doesn't match your description in the question.

Comment: @Barmar, I just added more info about that question sir. Im trying my own method which includes php-loop which is somehow long and confusing.

Comment: @starwberry, thanks for the info. I will look in to that topic right now.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT id, (qa1 = 'Y' + qa2 = 'Y' + ... + qa20 = 'Y') AS yes_count,
           (qa1 = 'N' + qa2 = 'N' + ... + qa20 = 'N') AS no_count
FROM yourtable
```

As you can see, structuring your table this way makes queries like this complicated. It would be better if you used a table where each answer was in a different row. Then you could do

```
SELCT id, SUM(qa = 'Y') AS yes_count, SUM(qa = 'N') AS no_count
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY id
```

This table would be structured like:

```
CREATE TABLE yourTable (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL, -- Survey ID
    question_num INTEGER NOT NULL, -- 1 to 20
    qa CHAR(1), -- Y or N
    UNIQUE KEY (id, question_num)
)
```

Comment: Could you show me a sample of how should I design the table?

Comment: the above query didnt work for me, it return 0 result

Comment: I do not know how to make this work, it gives me Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Comment: Update your question showing what you tried. You probably made a typo.

Comment: The question said the values in the fields were `YES` and `NO`. When you posted the sample data it's just `y` and `n`. You need to compare with the correct strings in the query.

Comment: @barmar here's a sample of screenshot of the sample datas http://prntscr.com/5nl86y and I understand that it must be an exactly the same string for it to work.

Comment: My answer should work for that data, just fix the column names to match your table.

Comment: @barmar, thanks for the help. I figured out a way to get what I want w/o using such queries and also w/o renewing my table.

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer.

Comment: @barmar, I do not know how to do that. But I did post my answer just below the problem above.

Comment: Click on the `Answer Your Question` button at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Try This it gives me the result.

```
select count(*) from sample where  'yes' IN (q1,q2,q3,q4,q5,q6,q7,q8,q9......)
```

Comment: `COUNT(*)` counts rows, not columns.

Comment: This sir worked for me, its short and not confusing. Thank you.

Comment: This will return the number of rows where any question was answered `yes`. It won't return the number of `yes` answers on the row.

Comment: Oh, @barmar yes. It indeed only return the number of row. Got carried away since I'm figuring this out for like an hour now.

Answer (score 0):

I came to this solution after an hour of trials, It produce the result without using much queries.

```
$yescounter = 0;
$nocounter = 0;
for($x1 = 1; $x1<= 50; $x1++){
$answercounter1 = mysql_query("SELECT qanswer$x1 FROM tb_erm_exam_results WHERE qanswer$x1='y'");
$ac1 = mysql_num_rows($answercounter1);
if($ac1 == 1) { $yescounter++; } else { $nocounter++; }
}
```